# ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse: two applications in one url

Tags: apache, proxypass

I have 2 applications deployed on 2 servers:

- `http://10.10.10.5:8000`     - main application
- `http://10.10.10.6:80`       - help application

I would like these applications to be accessible from the following URLs:

- `http://protonnn.com`      - main application
- `http://protonnn.com/help` - help application

How should I configure the Apache default virtual hosts file in order to get above result? It is possible to do it?

IMPORTANT: Help application must have path context: /help  - in other case images and page styles don't be work

I have tried following configuration:

---

```
<VirtualHost*:80>

  ServerName protonnn.com 
  ServerAlias protonnn.com

  ProxyPass / http://10.10.10.5:8000
  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.10.5:8000

  ProxyPass /help http://10.10.10.6
  ProxyPassReverse /help http://10.10.10.6

  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

---

I have already have found a solution:

```
<VirtualHost*:80>

  ServerName protonnn.com 
  ServerAlias protonnn.com

  ProxyPass /help/ http:// 10.10.10.6/help/
  ProxyPassReverse/ /help http:// 10.10.10.6/help/

  ProxyPass / http:// 10.10.10.5:8000
  ProxyPassReverse / http:// 10.10.10.5:8000


  <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Location>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

---

Comment: SUre, it's possible, and you've even identified some Apache directives that are likely to help you out.  Did they work?  Were there errors?  Did you not understand part of the documentation?  Give us some specific questions and we can give you better answers.

Comment: Thanks for adding your configuration.  Now, how is it behaving?  Does anything work?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: what happens now?  did you restart/reload Apache?  Did it give any errors?  and in the browser?  tell us!  what's going on!??  :)

Comment: SOLUTION: ProxyPass /help/ http:// 10.10.10.6/help/ ProxyPassReverse/ /help http:// 10.10.10.6/help/

ProxyPass / http:// 10.10.10.5:8000 ProxyPassReverse / http:// 10.10.10.5:8000